# Scaling rendered image with cocos2d ruins image quality

Tags: image, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, scaling

Using Cocos2d (v 1.01), If I am displaying a sprite as is, I get it in good quality, but if I am using a CCRenderTexture, image quality is bad. This happens only if I scale up the image.

See attached screen shot, original image is on the left. [image]
This is my code:

```
CCScene* pScene = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene();

CCSprite* origSprite = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("jigsaw/11.png");
origSprite->setPosition(CCPoint(250,250));
origSprite->setScale(1.3);
pScene->addChild(origSprite, 500);

CCSprite* imageSprite = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("jigsaw/11.png");
CCSize imageSize = imageSprite->boundingBox().size;
CCRenderTexture *rt = CCRenderTexture::renderTextureWithWidthAndHeight(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
imageSprite->setPosition(ccp(imageSize.width/2, imageSize.height/2));
rt->begin();
imageSprite->visit();
rt->end();
CCSprite *newSprite = CCSprite::spriteWithTexture(rt->getSprite()->getTexture());
delete rt;
newSprite->setFlipY(true);
newSprite->setPosition(CCPoint(750,750));
newSprite->setScale(1.3);
pScene->addChild(newSprite, 500);
```

Comment: Are you scaling the image at all? Also, check your pixel formats are all the same both in cocos2d and when you save your image.

Comment: I omitted all scaling, same results.

Comment: I use kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888 pixel format. What do you mean by "when you save your image"? Thanks for you suggestions, BTW!

Comment: I do scale up the image. Without scaling, the images look the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the answer. I needed to add:

```
newSprite->getTexture()->setAntiAliasTexParameters();
```

Comment: It doesn't remove rendering aliasing (it is present in saved file). But it makes aliasing less noticeable when creating sprite from rendered texture.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but just try it,
Because i have also faced this problem and I had found this solution for my issue Hope this will help you also.

Just set the size and Position of the Render texture and Sprite

Like this >

```
renderTexture = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:1024 height:768];
      [renderTexture clear:1.0f 
                         g:1.0f
                         b:1.0f
                         a:1.0f];
      renderTexture.position = CGPointMake(500,380);
      [self addChild:renderTexture z:0 tag:1];


 sprite.anchorPoint=ccp(1,1);
        sprite.position =CGPointMake(530, 380);
        [renderTexture addChild:sprite];
```